# Reduce list manually in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am writing a simple OCaml function that creates an association list.  The input is a string which is converted to a list of non-unique words in same order as in string, then the output is an association list of (word, [indices in list]).

Example

```
let f "a b c b a b" = ...

expected output => [("a", [0,4]), ("b", [1,3,5]), ("c", [2])]  # order not important
```

So far I have managed to get to this intermediate output

```
[("b", 5); ("a", 4); ("b", 3); ("c", 2); ("b", 1); ("a", 0)]
```

but I am stuck trying to figure out how to reduce this to the final result.

Would it make more sense to create a `Hashtbl` from the original input?  Then `Hashtbl` -> `list`??

Or is it a simple matter to reduce the intermediate result?  The environment I am working in does not have access to `List.reduce`, so I would have to write a reduce function manually.

As I look at this it seems a `Hashtbl` would be more efficient as the number of words grows.

EDIT: `Hashtbl` definitely seems like the way to go. I already have the following hashtable:

```
"a" : [4,0], "b" : [5,3,1], "c" : [2]
```

But I can not figure out how to convert to a list now.  `Hashtbl.iter` operates on every individual binding so, for example, it iterates over `("a", 4)` and `("a", 0)` separately (my understanding) which defeats the purpose. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your description of the hashtable. Is the type of the hashtable `(string, int) Hashtbl.t` or is it `(string, int list) Hashtbl.t`? If it's the latter, you can just use `Hashtbl.iter` or (possibly better) `Hashtbl.fold`.

If your hashtable is of type `(string, int) Hashtbl.t` you could perhaps rewrite your code to keep a list of ints instead of an individual int. Then it will be of type `(string, int list) Hashtbl.t`.

**Update**

If your hashtable is of type `(string, int list) Hashtbl.t` then you can just use `iter` or `fold` if you make sure you have only one entry for each key.

The document is describing the following phenomenon:

```
# let h = Hashtbl.create 10;;
val h : ('_a, '_b) Hashtbl.t = <abstr>
# Hashtbl.add h "a" 3;;
- : unit = ()
# Hashtbl.add h "a" 4;;
- : unit = ()
# h;;
- : (string, int) Hashtbl.t = <abstr>
# Hashtbl.iter (fun s i -> Printf.printf "%s %d\n" s i) h;;
a 4
a 3
- : unit = ()
#
```

If you use `Hashtbl.add` to add new entries to a hashtable without removing the old ones, the entries accumulate.

If you use `Hashtbl.replace` rather than `Hashtbl.add`, things will work more reasonably.

```
# let h = Hashtbl.create 10;;
val h : ('_a, '_b) Hashtbl.t = <abstr>
# Hashtbl.replace h "a" 3;;
- : unit = ()
# Hashtbl.replace h "a" 4;;
- : unit = ()
# h;;
- : (string, int) Hashtbl.t = <abstr>
# Hashtbl.iter (fun s i -> Printf.printf "%s %d\n" s i) h;;
a 4
- : unit = ()
```

If you have a hashtable of the right type and use `Hashtbl.replace` to update your entries you will be OK.

Comment: its a (string, int list) Hashtbl.t.  But when I read docs on Hashtbl.iter (or fold) it sounds like it does not treat the list as one binding to the key, but instead each list element is a separate binding to the key.  Am I mistaken?  thx

Comment: Then you can just use `Hashtbl.iter` or `Hashtbl.fold`. Try it out!

Comment: was editing comment as you responded, thx again ...  " But when I read docs on Hashtbl.iter (or fold) it sounds like it does not treat the list as one binding to the key, but instead each list element is a separate binding to the key. Am I mistaken? thx "

Comment: I'll edit my answer. It will work as I describe if you make sure to clear the entry before adding a new one. Sorry for lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example using the `Core` library and associative lists.

open Core.Std

```
let compute str =
  let letters = String.split str ~on:' ' in
  let i = ref (-1) in
  List.fold letters ~init:[] ~f:(fun acc letter ->
      incr i;
      match List.Assoc.find acc letter with
      | Some l -> List.Assoc.add acc letter (List.append l [!i])
      | None -> List.Assoc.add acc letter [!i]
    )
```

Here is an example:

```
compute "a b c b a b";;

- : (string, int list) List.Assoc.t =
[("b", [1; 3; 5]); ("a", [0; 4]); ("c", [2])]
```

The trick here is to use `List.fold` to iterate over the split string and update the associative list.

Answer (score 0):

Create Hashtbl

```
let my_hash = Hashtbl.create 12;;
let l=[("b", 5); ("a", 4); ("b", 3); ("c", 2); ("b", 1); ("a", 0)] ;;
List.iter (fun (k,v) -> 
  Hashtbl.add  my_hash k v 
) l;;
```

Program

```
let (opt_k',kacc,l)= 
  Hashtbl.fold ( fun k v (opt_k',kacc,l) ->
    match opt_k' with 
      | None    -> (Some k,v::kacc,l) 
      | Some k' -> if k=k' then (opt_k',v::kacc,l) else (Some k,v::[],(k',kacc)::l) 
  ) my_hash (None,[],[]) 
in
match opt_k' with 
  | Some k' -> List.rev ((k',kacc)::l)
  | _       -> List.rev l
;;
- : (string * int list) list = [("a", [4; 0]); ("b", [5; 3; 1]); ("c", [2])]
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard library function `List.fold_left` covers the functionality that `reduce` provides in Lisp languages as well as in Core. You can use either hash tables or maps to build the result incrementally. While you can also use basic association lists from the `List` module, you risk worst case O(n^2) performance.

Thus:

```
module StringMap = Map.Make(String)

(* Extract words from a string. *)
let words = Str.split (Str.regexp "[ \t]+")

(* Build a string to int list dictionary from a string of words. *)
let dict ws =
  let open StringMap in
  let dict' =
    (* Go through each word in turn; 'i' is a counter that is being
     * incremented, 'mapping' accumulates the results. *)
    List.fold_left (fun (mapping, i) word ->
      try
        let positions = find word mapping in
        (* Add to existing entry *)
        (add word (i :: positions) mapping, i+1)
      with
        (* New entry *)
        Not_found -> (add word [i] mapping, i+1))
      (empty, 0) in
  let (mapping, _) = dict' (words ws) in
  (* Entries are in reverse order, sort them out, then return as list. *)
  (* The bindings themselves are already sorted. *)
  bindings (map List.rev mapping)

let example = dict "a b c b a b"
```

This provides keys and positions in sorted order. The last line of `dict` can be simplified to `bindings mapping` if order does not matter.

Note that this requires the `Str` module to parse the string into a list of words and thus `str.cma` (for byte code compilation) or `str.cmxa` (for native code compilation) needs to be passed to the compiler, e.g.: `ocamlc str.cma dict.ml`. If you're using ocamlbuild, build with `-package str`.